# Strong Typed names for DbType

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Is there a class with properties for the names for `DbType` so that I can change the `DbType = "DATETIME2"` in the following to `DbType = DbNames.DateTime2`:

```
[Column(Name = "Date", DbType = "DATETIME2", CanBeNull = false)]
public DateTime Date;
```

Comment: Maybe you could create subclasses of ColumnAttribute, like `DateTime2ColumnAttribute`.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. It's a shame, though, if there really isn't something built in. At least for Sql Server. After all it's Microsoft's database.

Comment: Considering that each individual feature in the framework must be tested and requires an army of 200+ translators for documentation I can imagine they strive for the absolute minimum. Anyway, it's not there and that's what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are database specific variations of this enum e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2 but they don't contain constant strings of the specific types you outline as a requirement.

Why not define your own? You can take some of the pain out of the typing, if you are using a db for which there is a xxxDbType enum, by writing a switch for it and tab-tabbing. This will make VS prepopulate your switch with list of case: statements for every enum member; then a quick bit of find/replace and uppercasing should generate your const declarations..

Comment: Thanks. +1. It's a shame, though, if there really isn't something built in. At least for Sql Server. After all it's Microsoft's database.

Comment: What data access library is this?

Comment: LinqToSql. (I put it in the tags.)

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to look at the tags. Just wanted to point out that if you use SQLMetal to generate your client side context, it should fill in all the DbType for you. Is there a reason you're not using it?